# is there any limitation number for pairing to multi android devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to pair my device to 100 number of Bluetooth devices and each 1 min I will connect to one of them and get data then disconnect and reconnect to the next one till the end.
is there any limitation for the number of devices I can pair with?

Answer (score 0):

In the AOSP implementation, Bluedroid Bluetooth stack default configuration is to pair upto 100 devices. But it might not be the same with your phone. You can compile the Bludroid/fludroid stack with support for 100 devices or more(in /system/bt/include/bt_target.h). So android can support more than 100 paired devices. But you have to check the BT controller in phone can store 100 link keys.